# Add an index column to a csv using awk

Tags: linux, csv, indexing, awk

How can I add an index to a csv file using awk?  For example lets assume I have a file

**data.txt**

```
col1,col2,col3
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
a3,b3,c3
```

I would like to add another column, which is the index.  Basically I would like an output of

```
,col1,col2,col3
0,a1,b1,c1
1,a2,b2,c2
2,a3,b3,c3
```

I was trying to use `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'` but it does not seem to be working right.  And what is the best way to just add a comma for the first line but add incrementing number and a comma to the rest of the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{print (NR == 1 ? "" : NR-2) "," $0}' file

,col1,col2,col3
0,a1,b1,c1
1,a2,b2,c2
2,a3,b3,c3
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  How does NR-2 get the incrementing numbers?  I know the rest is more of a conditional statement, that if its the first line its be blank, but a bit confused how the NR-2 thing works

Comment: Oh its the line number, minus 2.. got it lol

Comment: Other alternative would be an increment `awk '{print (NR==1?"":n++)","$0}' file`. They are essentially the same, the only reason I mention it is a stray curiosity whether subtraction or post-increment would save a few clock-cycles over the other. No clue which way it would go.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe '$_ = ( $. > 1 ? ($. - 2) : "" ) . ",$_";' data.txt > out.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
col1,col2,col3
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
a3,b3,c3
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print NR==1?"":i++,$0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
,col1,col2,col3
0,a1,b1,c1
1,a2,b2,c2
2,a3,b3,c3
```

Explanation: firstly I inform GNU `AWK` that output field separator (`OFS`) is `,`, so arguments to `print` will be concatenated using that character. Then for each line I use so-called *ternary operator* i.e. *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse* to decide what will be 1st argument, for 1st line (`NR==1`) it is empty string for all else it is counter which will be first returned **then** increased by 1, 2nd argument to print is always whole original line (`$0`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Would actually be fine in any awk, mawk, gawk, etc...

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> gawk 'sub("^",substr(++_",",3^(NF~NR)))' FS='^$' \_=-2
> ```

> ```
> mawk 'sub("^",++_+NF ? _",":",")' FS='^$' \_=-2
> ```

```
,col1,col2,col3
0,a1,b1,c1
1,a2,b2,c2
2,a3,b3,c3
```